# Crop Node doesn't work

Tags: node-editor

Compositor Workspace:

The **crop node** doesn't work, as even when I put the numbers to the highest value, the **movie clip** still **doesn't appear**.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi,  please [edit] your question and add images that show your compositing nodes and result. If you wish, you may also share a simplified version of your file via [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).Thanks :)

Comment: Did you press F12?